# Use GSON to map changing field name to POJO

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am writing an `Android` app, and using `RetroFit` to communicate with the REST API. I have all the classes/POJO's written, except one.

Here is the Java for the specific class.
This is the parent class, which is the root of the problem. I need to be able to map the `userNameResponse` variable to the users name in the `JSON` below

```
public class DiTopicStats {

    private UserNameResponse userNameResponse;

    public UserNameResponse getUserNameResponse() {
        return userNameResponse;
    }

    public void setUserNameResponse(UserNameResponse userNameResponse) {
        this.userNameResponse = userNameResponse;
    }
}
```

and the child class, which should be fine as long as I can map to it from the above parent class:

```
public class UserNameResponse {

    //Fields
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

The JSON that is returned contains a field which changes per response. The field is the users name. For example:

```
{
    "sMessage": "",
    "diStatus": {
        "diTopicWrongAns": {
            //Some fields
        },
        "diOverallStats": {
            //Some more fields
        },
        "diUserStats": {
            "John Smith": { //PROBLEM: This name changes
                //some other fields
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case, the name "John Smith" has a dynamic field name. Realistically, it could be any string with letters, numbers, a `-` or a `.` in it.

My question is, using RetroFit, how can I create a Java class that lets RetroFit map a field to a variable?

I'm aware you can specify a `SerialisedName` but can this be done programatically at runtime, because I will have the `name` or the user at this stage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pojo called DiUserStats and then define a custom GsonTypeAdapter e.g.

```
public class DiUserStatsTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<DiUserStats>, JsonSerializer<DiUserStats> {

    @Override
    public DiUserStats deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        DiUserStats target = new DiUserStats();
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> object =(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>)jsonObject.entrySet().toArray()[0];
        target.setName(object.getKey());
        JsonObject targetValues = object.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
        /*parse values to your DiUserStats as documented using targetValues.get("fooProperty").getAsString(), etc */
        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(DiUserStats src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject values = new JsonObject();
        values.addProperty("foo", src.getFoo);
        obj.addProperty(target.getName(), values);
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Then when you setup Gson use a builder and add your custom type adapter e.g.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(DiUserStats.class, new DiUserStatsTypeAdapter()).create();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Quick question though. What is `JsonSerialized`? Android Studio can't find it to import it.

Comment: I see there is a typo there.  It should be JsonSerializer<T> not JsonSerialzied<T>